# How to access list containing 500000 elements and each element in list should be lesser than 1500000 (Python)?

Tags: python-3.x, list, time-complexity, python-itertools

List containing `500000` elements, i.e., `size of list`.

And each element in list should be lesser than `1500000`.

```
l1 = [1]*500000
for i in range(len(l1)):
    if l1[i] <= 1500000:
        print("valid)
```

Above approach will take more time to loop (`may error out if size is greater than 500000`)
I know this is not right approach. May be `itertools` or something better would be ideal.

```
Could you please help me to handle in efficient way ?
```

If a user is inputting such values, how to read them ? any `specific/faster` way to accept those values ? or just `input()`

Comment: You want to store the values which are less than 1500 from the list of 500000 elements, right?

Comment: @Alok : not to store those elements. If any of the elements value greater than 1500000, should not proceed further.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use [numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/user/index.html) for faster this, with list and any tool you can't do faster than numpy array

```
import numpy as np
# generating random list(numpy array of 500000 elements with random between 0 and 10000 )
l1 = np.random.randint(0,10000, (500000,))
#print all elements whose greter than 1500
print(l1[l1 > 1500])
```

for numpy operators visit [this](https://www.tutorialgateway.org/python-numpy-comparison-operators/) and [this](https://www.quora.com/In-Python-what-is-NumPy-How-is-it-used?share=1)